# Traduction de « debugging » en « déverminage »

Tags: anglais, anglicismes, informatique

Dans un document décrivant un logiciel, un collègue a écrit

> Afin de faciliter le déverminage, ...

Il m'a fallu une seconde de réflexion pour comprendre qu'il voulait parler de *debugging*.

Quelles traduction proposez-vous ? Puis-je garder le terme anglais ? J'aurais personnellement choisi le néologisme anglicisant de *débuggage*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Je vois / j'utilise plus souvent **débogage** ( et en plus, ça a l'air d'être la [traduction officielle](http://www.presse-francophone.org/apfa/defi/d/debogage.htm))

> **DÉBOGAGE**, n. m.
>
> *Domaine* : informatique.
>
> *Définition* : action d'éliminer les bogues
>
> *Anglais* : debugging.
>
> *Source* : arrêté du 30 décembre 1983 (J.O. du 19 février 1984).

On trouve aussi des orthographes moins courantes comme débuggage, débugage, ou encore déboggage.

Comment: C'est ce que confirme [Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais?query=debugging&source=english) aussi

Answer (score 4):

*Déverminage* et *debugging* ne désignent pas la même action. *Déverminage* désigne un rodage systématique

> **déverminage**, masculin
>   […] 1. (Composants électroniques) Séquences de contraintes thermiques, ou climatiques, ou électriques, ou mécaniques, ayant pour but d’éliminer les défauts de jeunesse dans une production donnée de composants électroniques. [[Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9verminage)]

Traduit par [*burn-in period*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/burn-in+period).

Alors que *debugging* désigne une correction manuelle des erreurs de fonctionnement.

> **de·bug**, verb (used with object),
>   […] 1. to detect and remove defects or errors from.
>   […] 3. Computers . to detect and remove errors from (a computer program). [[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/debugging)]

Traduire l'un par l'autre est donc un contresens.

Pour trouver une autre traduction, en ce qui me concerne, *débugging*, *debugging*, *débugage* conviennent. Par contre je trouve *débogage* assez étrange : pourquoi *o* ? On le prononce [o] ou [ɔ] ? De mémoire [ʌ] est plutôt perçu comme [œ], donc quitte à transcrire, pourquoi pas *débeugage* ou *débœugage* ?

Comment: Ma foi, la la Délégation générale à la langue française et aux langues de France a recommandé en 1983 de franciser _a bug_ en _une bogue_. Son équivalent québécois prônait depuis longtemps le même, mais dans un genre masculin, et c'est ce qu'ont suivi aussi les grands dictionnaires. J'ai un doute sur la prononciation dans ce cas.

Comment: Et ton [*débœugage* est unique sur le web](http://www.google.fr/search?cx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=d%C3%A9b%C5%93ugage)

Comment: Tssk, te voici bien prescriptif. Comme rds, j'ai vu *déverminage* utilisé pour *debugging*, et j'ai mis quelques secondes à comprendre. Je suis d'accord que cet usage est malvenu, puisqu'il est incompris par des professionnels du domaine.

Comment: @Gilles Chacun fait ce qu'il veut, mais je ne le ferais pas et je ne le conseille pas, surtout s'il y a risque de confusion. C'est être prescriptif ?

Comment: @rds Ouaip, je néologise, moi, monsieur.